# Stack a div ontop of a bootstrap navbar that hides on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for a website and I'm trying to create a div that would sit above the navbar on an unscrolled website but when I begin scrolling it would disappear and the navbar would fill the spot.

I have it "working" using this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs col-md-offset-8 col-sm-offset-8" style="padding:2px 0 3px 0;">
            <span class="btcall">Call for a free quote call - <span class="badge"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i> 1300 123 456</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
etc etc
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
     top:25px;
 }

nav a {
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 30px !important;
  margin-top:-15px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.shrink {
    top:0px;
}

 nav.navbar.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
}

nav.shrink a {
  padding-top: 15px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

It's not ideal and I feel it can be done smarter but I'm not sure how. Essentially I'd love it to be fixed to the nav and hidden on scroll rather than stuck in place and only appear if the browser it scrolled RIGHT to the top.

Comment: What don't you like about your current script? Would you mind explaining a little bit further?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your nav bar is fixed to the top of the window, your nav bar scrolls with the page, and you want a div to appear above that bar only when the user is scrolled to the top of the page, the below will work.

If that's not quite what you need, please explain the ui in more detail, or better yet create a jsfiddle

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.hideMe').fadeOut('slow');
  } else {
    $('.hideMe').fadeIn('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
.floatMenu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}

/* below this line is only for my made up example navigation*/

li {
    display: inline;
}
.pre-container{
  background-color:#cccccc;
}

.hideMe{
  background-color:#999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pre-container floatMenu">
<div class="container hideMe">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-md-offset-8 col-sm-offset-8" style="padding:2px 0 3px 0;"> 
      <span class="btcall">Call for a free quote call - </span>
      <span class="badge"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i> 1300 123 456</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<nav  class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
  <!--im making up a menu for my example-->
  <ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
</div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: I took a part of your code and then rearranged the DIVs for my code and got it to work, so thanks :)